Mystery Bug Fix in Electron v26 and Mac App Store build
I have an Electron app that uses a native add-on to access the Photos library on macOS. This feature didn't work in the MAS (Mac App Store) build when the sandbox is enabled.
Here is what I observed:

When built without the sandbox, the app can access the Photos library.
When built with the sandbox and Electron v26 or later, the app can access the Photos library.
When built with the sandbox and Electron v25 or earlier, the app cannot access the Photos library. Instead, some XPC errors are reported.

CoreData: XPC: sendMessage: failed #0
CoreData: XPC: Unable to sendMessage: to server
...
CoreData: XPC: sendMessage: failed #7
CoreData: XPC: Unable to connect to server with options {
    NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey = 1;
    NSXPCStoreServerEndpointFactory = "<PLXPCPhotoLibraryStoreEndpointFactory: 0x7fc67e8af370>";
    skipModelCheck = 1;
}
CoreData: XPC: Unable to load metadata: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={Problem=Unable to send to server; failed after 8 attempts.}
CoreData: fault: Unable to create token NSXPCConnection.  NSXPCStoreServerEndpointFactory 0x7fc67e8af370 -newEndpoint returned nil
CoreData: error: Failed to create NSXPCConnection

Since Electron v26 is no longer supported by the official team, I am wondering if anyone here could explain why this is happening.
I tested Electron v25.9.8, which produces the same XPC errors, while v26.0.0 works just fine. Here are the related release notes:

Electron 26
Node 18.16.0
Node 18.16.1


So what is your problem here, then? If it works in Electron 26 and later, why don't you just upgrade? This could be a problem anywhere in your app, Electron, or your "native add-on", which may expect a newer Electron version (if it's specifically for Electron and you don't have written it yourself). Without any of that info, it's hard to say why that happened. Also, you won't get it fixed for unsupported Electron versions (if it's a problem with Electron).

@AlexanderLeithner Thank you for your comments. I am simply curious about WHY, I understand there probably won't be fixed.
